# Redirecting from the main page to another controller in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, redirect

When I launch my Grails app. It always show the index.gsp page which is the main page. I want to make sure if user is logged in, the user gets redirected to Home.gsp instead of landing on Index.gsp of the main page. Is there a way doing that ?

Comment: Are you using spring security?

Comment: yes. I am not guarding my landing page as I want people to be able to visit it without being logedin.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a IndexController:

```
class IndexController {
    def index() {
        redirect(controller: 'avaliacao', action: 'listar', id: 1)
    }
}
```

My app is integrated with Spring Security + CAS and after login the user is redirected to the controller/action specified above.

If you need to redirect to a specific gsp without a controller:

```
class IndexController {
    def index() {
        redirect uri:'/home'
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change your UrlMappings.groovy adding the following line:

```
"/home"(view:"/home")
```

This consider that you have a home.gsp located at root of views folder.

My RequestMap (Spring Security) was confiure this way:

permitAll - /home